# SQL Server STRING_AGG function sorting is not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, string-agg

I've broken my head against this issue trying to reproduce it on a dynamically generated data set, but it finally worked out!

This is the code

```
;with tbl as
(
    select Id,  ClCode, Manager,    ChangeDate
    from (values
    (1, '000005',   'Cierra Vega',      '2017-10-05'),
    (2, '000005',   'Alden Cantrell',   '2017-11-29'),
    (3, '000005',   'Alden Cantrell',   '2017-11-30'),
    (4, '000005',   'Kierra Gentry',    '2018-09-05'),
    (5, '000005',   'Kierra Gentry',    '2018-09-12'),
    (6, '000005',   'Pierre Cox',       '2018-11-06'),
    (7, '000005',   'Thomas Crane',     '2019-09-11'),
    (8, '000005',   'Thomas Crane',     '2019-10-01'),
    (9, '000005',   'Miranda Shaffer',  '2020-04-27'),
    (10,'000360',   'Bradyn Kramer',    '2017-10-06')
    ) as t(Id, ClCode, Manager, ChangeDate)
)
, grouped as                        
(                       
    select c.ClCode
    , count(distinct c.Manager) [ManagerChangesCount]
    , STRING_AGG(c.[Manager], ',') within group (order by c.MinChangeDate) [Managers]
    , STRING_AGG(c.MinChangeDate, ',') within group (order by c.MinChangeDate) [ChangeDates]
    from (                  
        select x.ClCode
        , x.[Manager]
        , min(x.ChangeDate) [MinChangeDate] 
        from tbl x
        group by x.ClCode, x.[Manager]  
    ) c                 
    group by c.ClCode                   
)
select *
from grouped
```

My sample dataset contains data about when (ChangeDate) certain clients (ClCode) had their manager (Manager) changed. It is a part of the real DWH Clients dimension table (SCD Type 2), so these "duplicates" just contain changes in the other columns somewhere.

What I'm trying to achieve: I need a list of client codes with how many times their manager was changed and a comma separated list of these manager names sorted from left to right in their change order

```
ClCode  ManagerChangesCount             Managers                                                                            ChangeDates
000005  6                               Cierra Vega,Alden Cantrell,Kierra Gentry,Pierre Cox,Thomas Crane,Miranda Shaffer    2017-10-05,2017-11-29,2018-09-05,2018-11-06,2019-09-11,2020-04-27
000360  1                               Bradyn Kramer                                                                       2017-10-06
```

But in fact I receive results without or with some weird sorting

```
ClCode  ManagerChangesCount Managers                                                                                        ChangeDates
000005  6                               Alden Cantrell,Cierra Vega,Kierra Gentry,Miranda Shaffer,Pierre Cox,Thomas Crane    2017-11-29,2017-10-05,2018-09-05,2020-04-27,2018-11-06,2019-09-11
000360  1                               Bradyn Kramer                                                                       2017-10-06
```

This query returns good sorting:

1. if I remove `, count(distinct c.Manager) [ManagerChangesCount]`
2. if I remove string id=10 (second client)
3. if I add a filtering condition where `where ClCode = '000005'`
4. if I get rid of duplicate rows in a dataset and remove group by from a subquery

But all the same for me it looks like a bug... I mean unsorted results from my query

Guys, if you can figure this out, please help me to understand why sorting is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I do agree that the behaviour you're getting shouldn't be happening, however, Stack Overflow isn't for reporting bugs with applications. For SQL Server, that should be done in their [Azure Feedback portal](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/filters/new?category_id=325153).

As for resolving the issue, removing the redundant `DISTINCT` from your `COUNT` causes the problem to disappear. To implement a `DISTINCT` (either in a `SELECT DISTINCT` or a `COUNT(DISTINCT {expression})`) SQL Server needs to first sort the results as then it can easily remove any values that have the same sort position. As a result that sort is being expressed in your `STRING_AGG` expressions, even though they have an explicit `ORDER BY` clause.

The reason I say your `DISTINCT` is redundant is because at that point in the query there will be no duplicate values of `Manager` for a given value of `ClCode`. This is because you already grouped on both `Manager` and `ClCode` in the subquery. If you run that query alone, you'll see that `Manager` doesn't have any duplicates:

```
WITH tbl AS
    (SELECT Id,
            ClCode,
            Manager,
            ChangeDate
     FROM (VALUES (1, '000005', 'Cierra Vega', '2017-10-05'),
                  (2, '000005', 'Alden Cantrell', '2017-11-29'),
                  (3, '000005', 'Alden Cantrell', '2017-11-30'),
                  (4, '000005', 'Kierra Gentry', '2018-09-05'),
                  (5, '000005', 'Kierra Gentry', '2018-09-12'),
                  (6, '000005', 'Pierre Cox', '2018-11-06'),
                  (7, '000005', 'Thomas Crane', '2019-09-11'),
                  (8, '000005', 'Thomas Crane', '2019-10-01'),
                  (9, '000005', 'Miranda Shaffer', '2020-04-27'),
                  (10, '000360', 'Bradyn Kramer', '2017-10-06')) t (Id, ClCode, Manager, ChangeDate) )
SELECT x.ClCode,
       x.[Manager],
       MIN(x.ChangeDate) AS [MinChangeDate]
FROM tbl x
GROUP BY x.ClCode,
         x.[Manager];
```

As such, the `DISTINCT` in the `COUNT` is just added overhead for the instance, as it's not required (SQL Server has already sorted the data for the `GROUP BY` so why ask it to sort it again?). If you *Are* using a `DISTINCT` in a query you've already aggregated, then you very likely don't need it.